# Getting data from first and last row of each group

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I've found many similar topics to this but none I can understand well enough to solve my specific case.

A have a table with the following basic structure:

```
+------------------------+
| id | session ID | bal  |
+------------------------+
| 0  | 00000002 | 100    |
| 1  | 00000002 | 120    |
| 2  | 00000002 | 140    |
| 3  | 00000001 | 900    |
| 4  | 00000001 | 800    |
| 5  | 00000001 | 500    |
+------------------------+
```

I need to create a (Microsoft SQL) query which returns each unique sessionID along with the first ("start") and last ("end") bal entries based on sequencial value of the ID column. The result would look like this:

```
+---------------------------+
| session ID | start | end  |
+---------------------------+
| 00000002   | 100   | 140  |
| 00000001   | 900   | 500  |
+---------------------------+
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Can you create a sqlfiddle?

Comment: OP Mentions SQL Server in the post...  Are you looking for just the `min()` and `max()`, or are you asking for the first and last based on the `id` field?

Comment: I think you might benefit from looking into some of the basics: [`GROUP BY`](http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-GROUP-BY.asp) and the associated [`MAX`](http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-MAX.asp) and [`MIN`](http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-MIN.asp) aggregate functions will solve your problems

Comment: I was asking for the first and last based on the ID field, if you look at my desired results table you can see that start can be higher than end, or vice versa. So min() and max() answers given below do not work..

Comment: Your desired results is inverted. Not?

Answer (score 12):

**EDIT** In reply to your comment, SQL Server supports window functions.  One way to look up the first and last `bal` values per `Session ID` is:

```
select  distinct [Session ID]
,       first_value(bal) over (partition by [Session ID] order by id) as [start]
,       first_value(bal) over (partition by [Session ID] order by id desc) as [end]
from    Table1
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6c244/5/0)

Another way (there are many) is increasing and decreasing row numbers:

```
select  [Session ID]
,       max(case when rn1 = 1 then bal end) as [start]
,       max(case when rn2 = 1 then bal end) as [end]
from    (
        select  row_number() over (partition by [Session ID] order by id) as rn1
        ,       row_number() over (partition by [Session ID] order by id desc) as rn2
        ,       *
        from    Table1
        ) as SubQueryAlias
group by
        [Session ID]
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6c244/5/0)

Comment: Looks like they are ordered by the id column and sometimes go high to low.

Comment: Correct.. Min and Max are not relevant here if you look at my desired results table. I need to get the first and last bal values based on ID.

Comment: The first solution is actually correct, although IMHO using last_value (and ID ASC) for the third column would have been clearer.  

Here is a solution that works with 2005 - 2008R2
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8fe4a/10/0

Comment: @JimV.: I don't think `last_value` does what you think it does.  It's not the opposite of `first_value`.

Comment: @Andomar `last_value()` actually *is* the opposite of `first_value()`. The default "window frame" for the functions ('UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW') causes them to behave otherwise.  If you specify equivalent window frames ('UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ') the functions behave as one would expect.  

That being said, I did not know this when I made my original off the cuff statement.  Thanks for pointing the difference out.  

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6c244/31/0

Comment: @JimV.: [Asked on DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/76726/820), they came to the same conclusion

Comment: Your solution is correct. I just want to add that `FIRST_VALUE` is only available on SQL Server 2012 and later.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `JOIN` and [Common Table Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) for readability:

```
with CTE as
(
    select 
        sessionId, min(id) as firstId, max(id) as lastId
    from 
        log
    group by sessionId
)
select
    CTE.sessionId, Log1.bal as start, Log2.bal as [end]
from
    CTE
    join Log as Log1 on Log1.id = CTE.firstId
    join Log as Log2 on Log2.id = CTE.lastId
```

See the [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8fe4a/26/0).

Comment: You're not referring to the derived table more than once, so the CTE is superfluous.  [Example here.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8fe4a/34/0)

Comment: @Andomar You're right. I just started to write it with the multiple derived table references in mind. Anyway, It's very simple to understand and useful technique, so I'll keep it.

Comment: @Andomar I think you could add the change you made to my query in your answer, as it seems to me even simpler than the ones you've suggested.

Comment: Window functions can often work with just a single table scan.  So I prefer the variant with window functions even if it is a bit less clear

Comment: @Andomar I see. Anyway, the SQL Fiddle shows that in this case this approach did two more sorts, surpassing the total cost of the two table scan. So I prefer to put effort in readability first and tuning when necessary (and only the real database can tell when).

Comment: That's certainly the best approach :)

Answer (score 2):

I assume bal is numeric (although it doesn't have to be in this case, as all entries have length 3)

```
select sessionID
     , min(bal) as start
     , max(bal) as end
from table_name
group by sessionID
```

where "table_name" is the name of your table

Comment: The min and max of balance aren't the correct results.

Comment: You're right - I read the problem wrong.  The third entry (the one beginning with "with CTE as") is how I would do it - at least, if I didn't know that SQL now has analytic functions (which is how I would do it in Oracle).

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL may be like this:

```
SELECT `session ID`, MIN(bal) AS start, MAX(bal) AS end FROM `yourtable` WHERE `session ID` IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT(`session ID`) FROM `yourtable`
);
```

Comment: What is the `in` clause supposed to accomplish?  The question is about Microsoft SQL (or SQL Server) btw

Comment: Yes, I asked in MySQL because is what I dominate, now you has to "trasnlate" to SQL Server.

Answer (score -1):

> SELECT FIRST(column_name), LAST(column_name) FROM table_name;
>   http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?65,363723,363723